# Capitalization of "President" and "State" [of the United States]

Tags: capitalization

We used to capitalize references to  "the President" (of the US) even when his name wasn't included. And we used to capitalize "state" even when a particular state (State of California) was not mentioned. Is it now considered proper usage not to capitalize either of those?

Comment: Are you sure there has been a change over time?

Comment: The words are capitalized or not depending on how the word is being used.  There is no doubt some difference between "formal" and "informal", but the basic "rules' are fairly static (if obscure).

Comment: The irresistible question is *who's "we"*?

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate of the substance of the question that Hot Licks links to in a comment above. It's unfortunate that the accepted answer there is flawed by a misstatement regarding the recommendation in _The Chicago Manual of Style_ for handling "president Obama" versus "President Obama." (_Chicago_ prefers the latter style.)

Answer (score 0):

The word *state* isn't generally capitalized because it doesn't form part of the name of a state.  For instance, you may check with the [act](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/An+Act+for+the+Admission+of+the+State+of+California+into+the+Union) that granted statehood to California.  All references in the text are to "the state of California."

However, there are two idiosyncratic states -- the [Commonwealth of Pennsylvania](http://sites.state.pa.us/PA_Constitution.html) and the [Commonwealth of Massachusetts](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/Constitution).  Those initial-cap names are designated in their constitutions at the links.  Of course, they're still lower-case states.

Comment: I grew up in Washington, and it still peeves me that journalists refer to the city Washington, D.C. as "Washington" and the state as "Washington S(s)tate".  

The name of the state is not "Washington S(s)tate".      (That's the name of a university in Pullman, WA, fondly nicknamed "Wazzu".)

So that seems to be another exception.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock I'm a copy editor for a paper in Washington and AP style requests the term "Washington state" be used instead of "Washington State" for that very reason.

Comment: By Washington I mean the state north of Oregon haha. Everyone I know calls the other Washington DC in all usage